# Update only 2 field in DRF

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, drf-queryset

I  have a model and with DRF I want update only 2 field in model but when I update , 2 field are update but the other fields are empty .

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def snippet_detail(request, format=None):
    try:
        requestd = request.POST['card_number']
        requestd2 = card.models.Card(card_number=requestd)
        #snippet = Card.objects.get()
        print(requestd2)
        credit = Card.objects.filter(card_number=requestd).values('initial_credit')
        credit2 = int(credit[0]['initial_credit'])
        requestcredit = int(request.POST['initial_credit'])
        #print(snippet)
        print(credit)
        print(credit2)


    except Card.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = CardModelSerializer(requestd2, data=request.data, partial=True) #insted of requestd 2 was snippet
        if serializer.is_valid():
            #print(request.data)
            new_credit= credit2 - requestcredit
            comment = 'اعتبار کافی نمی باشد .'
            comment2 = 'مقدار وارد شده صحیح نمی باشد'
            if new_credit >= 0:
                if requestcredit >0:
                    serializer.save()
                    return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
                else:
                    return Response (comment2, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            else:

                return  Response(comment, status=status.HTTP_451_UNAVAILABLE_FOR_LEGAL_REASONS)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 2):

For partial `update` you can use `PATCH` method instead of using `PUT`

basically `PUT` method needs to full object for update and `PATCH` method only needs those fields which you want to update.

so, you need to use PATCH method to update only two fields that you want to update.

#### ------ `PUT` vs `PATCH` -------

`PUT:` sends an enclosed entity of a resource to the server. If the entity already exists, the server updates its data. Otherwise, the server creates a new entity

`PATCH:` allows the modification of an entity of a resource. So, it can be applied to change only particular portions of an entity's data

so, in request decorator put `PATCH` method instead of `PUT` like this...

#### views.py

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'])
def snippet_detail(request, format=None):
```

Comment: No , this solution not work

Comment: put error trace back

Answer (score 0):

just put the data you want to leave behind before running serializer.save()

```
    request.data["name"] = requestd2.name
    request.data["name"] = requestd2.name
    request.data["name"] = requestd2.name
    serializer = CardModelSerializer(requestd2, data=request.data, partial=True) #insted of requestd 2 was snippet
    if serializer.is_valid():
```